Start RDP session window as normal instead of maximized
There seems to be some inconsistency in regard to how an RDP session is opened using:
Start-Process "$env:windir\system32\mstsc.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "/v:$ComputerName";

Sometimes it will open up as a maximized window, and others it won't.  It may have something to do with the state it was previously exited in?  Adding -WindowStyle Normal to the Start-Process will still open the RDP session as a maximized window.
Is there a way to pass through the 'Normal' window state to the RDP session using Start-Process or some alternative?
As always, any guidance is appreciated.

I'm not sure what you mean by "normal". In my head "normal" is full screen. /f and /w: and /h: are the options that would control that.

According to:
link
There are 3 states.  Minimized, Maximized and Restored.  Restored is also referred to as Normal.  -WindowStyle uses Normal instead of Restored for the state I am looking for.  I am not familiar with /f etc, how would those be leveraged with start-process?

The link I provided may have gotten me what I needed.  Investigating and will report back.

Just wanted to report back, never found a workaround/solution for this.
